# Getting R to skip certain index values with the help of if statements, within while loops

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have been through multiple R-while-if questions and I didn't find a similar one. Please guide me to the answer if it has been asked.

So I have a vector V of `N=200` entries of number `0`. Every entry signifies a "bin". I skip the first 3 bins, for separate reasons. Now for `i= 3:N` number of bins, I use a while loop.

- For each `i`th number of bin, I generate a random number between `0` and `1`.
- If the random number is less than a certain numerical value (here it's 0.66) then, I simply replace the `0` at index `i` in Vector `V` with 1 and at the same time, I want while loop to skip next two values.
- if the random number is greater than the numerical value, I simply consider the next `i`.

  Here's the code I am running:

  ```
  N = 200
  Time <- rep(0, N)
  Time <- replace(Time, 3, 1)
  i = 5
  while (i <= N){
  p <- runif(1)
   if(p < 0.66){
     i= i+ 2; replace(Time, i, 1)
    } else {
      i <- i+1
     }
   }
  ```

I am not very good at R, and this is the combination I have been trying to use, to get R to do what I want, but it's clearly not working. I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that most functions in `R` do not modify objects they are applied to. Instead, they return a modified version of the original object which you have to assign, either to a new object, or to the original one (update it).

So instead of just running `replace(Time, i, 1)` (which does not update the `Time` vector), you need to assign the modified version back to `Time` like this:

```
Time <- replace(Time, i, 1)
```

or, better yet, use square bracket notation to update directly:

```
Time[i] <- 1
```

Moreover, you need to update vector `Time`, `Time <- replace(Time, i, 1)`, before you update your index `i`, `i = i + 2`. If you want to apply your loop only to `i > 3`, then you need to set `i = 4`. Finally, in case `runif(1) < 0.66`, if you want to skip the next *two* entries in `Time`, you should update `i` as `i <- i + 3`.

To summarise, you should modify your loop as follows:

```r
N = 200
Time <- rep(0, N)
Time[3] <- 1
i <- 4

while (i <= N){
    p <- runif(1)
    if(p < 0.66){
        Time[i] <- 1
        i <- i + 3
    } else {
        i <- i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer! For a fully complete answer, you should strengthen your recommendation to use square bracket notation over functions like `replace` or `subset`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: @divibisan `replace` is `[<-`, so I'm not sure that criticism applies. I guess a real improvement for the OP would come from using vectorized code instead of a loop...

Comment: @Frank yes, `subset` is not a relevant function in this question. but i don't think vectorising this would be trivial, seeing that each step depends on the previous one?

Comment: @stasg You'd get a different outcome for a given seed, but could achieve the same distribution over outcomes by assigning 0-1 based on `w = runif(200) < 0.6` and then afterwards applying the rules: `w[1:3] = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE); w[c(which(w)+1L, which(w)+2L)] = FALSE; as.integer(w)` or something. (Not sure about this code... also, there may be more direct ways.)

Comment: @Frank: It's hard to say the best way to vectorize this program since it's not really clear (at least to me) what OP wants to do and so it's hard to say how to do it better. If you have an idea, though, you should write your own answer!

Comment: @divibisan Yeah, I agree. Hard to know if their real problem is necessarily iterative or not. This is a good answer for the points that we can be sure about.

Comment: @Frank Good point on `replace`, I didn't look at the source before. I still think it shouldn't be used for purposes of clarity, but you're right that there shouldn't be any risks to it.

Comment: Thank you @stasg, this worked. Also thank you to everybody in the comments. I am simulating a Poisson Process with dead period. So the 1's in the vector V (V is a vector of time-bins, 200 time-bins for a 2 second spike train) are where the spike happens in the timeline. I needed a code to ensure that no spike happens for a certain time period after each spike. That's why we skip two time bins, every time there's a `1` entry. 

This was for one spike train. I will need to reiterate it multiple times to get more spike train. Please let me know if changing something would help the process.